# Unexpected state occurred for AsyncDataSetIterator: runnable died or no data available

Tags: java, exception, neural-network, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to build a neural network using deep learning4j framework, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected state occurred for AsyncDataSetIterator: runnable died or no data available" this exception
```

Here is my code

```
package com.neuralnetwork;

import com.sliit.preprocessing.NormalizeDataset;
import com.sliit.ruleengine.RuleEngine;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.SequenceRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVSequenceRecordReader;
import org.deeplearning4j.eval.Evaluation;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.api.OptimizationAlgorithm;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.Updater;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.GravesLSTM;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.RnnOutputLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.deeplearning4j.util.ModelSerializer;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.DataSet;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.iterator.DataSetIterator;
import org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions.LossFunction;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
import weka.core.converters.CSVSaver;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Deep Belif Neural Network to detect frauds.
 */
public class FraudDetectorDeepBeilefNN {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FraudDetectorDeepBeilefNN.class);
    public int outputNum = 4;
    private int iterations = 5;
    private int seed = 1234;
    private MultiLayerNetwork model = null;
    public int HIDDEN_LAYER_COUNT = 8;
    public int numHiddenNodes = 21;
    public int inputs = 41;
    private String uploadDirectory = "D:/Data";
    private ArrayList < Map < String, Double >> roc;

    public FraudDetectorDeepBeilefNN() {    
    }

    public void buildModel() {    
        System.out.println("Build model....");
        iterations = outputNum + 1;
        NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder builder = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder();
        builder.iterations(iterations);
        builder.learningRate(0.001);
        // builder.momentum(0.01);
        builder.optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT);
        builder.seed(seed);
        builder.biasInit(1);
        builder.regularization(true).l2(1e-5);
        builder.updater(Updater.RMSPROP);
        builder.weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER);

        NeuralNetConfiguration.ListBuilder list = builder.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_LAYER_COUNT; i++) {

            GravesLSTM.Builder hiddenLayerBuilder = new GravesLSTM.Builder();
            hiddenLayerBuilder.nIn(i == 0 ? inputs : numHiddenNodes);
            hiddenLayerBuilder.nOut(numHiddenNodes);
            hiddenLayerBuilder.activation("tanh");
            list.layer(i, hiddenLayerBuilder.build());
        }

        RnnOutputLayer.Builder outputLayer = new RnnOutputLayer.Builder(LossFunction.MCXENT);
        outputLayer.activation("softmax");
        outputLayer.nIn(numHiddenNodes);
        outputLayer.nOut(outputNum);
        list.layer(HIDDEN_LAYER_COUNT, outputLayer.build());
        list.pretrain(false);
        list.backprop(true);
        MultiLayerConfiguration configuration = list.build();
        model = new MultiLayerNetwork(configuration);
        model.init();
        //model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(1));    
    }

    public String trainModel(String modelName, String filePath, int outputs, int inputsTot) throws NeuralException {

        try {

            System.out.println("Neural Network Training start");
            loadSaveNN(modelName, false);
            if (model == null) {

                buildModel();
            }
            System.out.println("modal" + model);
            System.out.println("file path " + filePath);
            File fileGeneral = new File(filePath);
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(fileGeneral);
            Instances instances = loader.getDataSet();
            instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes() - 1);
            StratifiedRemoveFolds stratified = new StratifiedRemoveFolds();
            String[] options = new String[6];
            options[0] = "-N";
            options[1] = Integer.toString(5);
            options[2] = "-F";
            options[3] = Integer.toString(1);
            options[4] = "-S";
            options[5] = Integer.toString(1);
            stratified.setOptions(options);
            stratified.setInputFormat(instances);
            stratified.setInvertSelection(false);
            Instances testInstances = Filter.useFilter(instances, stratified);
            stratified.setInvertSelection(true);
            Instances trainInstances = Filter.useFilter(instances, stratified);
            String directory = fileGeneral.getParent();
            CSVSaver saver = new CSVSaver();
            File trainFile = new File(directory + "/" + "normtrainadded.csv");
            File testFile = new File(directory + "/" + "normtestadded.csv");
            if (trainFile.exists()) {

                trainFile.delete();
            }
            trainFile.createNewFile();
            if (testFile.exists()) {

                testFile.delete();
            }
            testFile.createNewFile();
            saver.setFile(trainFile);
            saver.setInstances(trainInstances);
            saver.writeBatch();
            saver = new CSVSaver();
            saver.setFile(testFile);
            saver.setInstances(testInstances);
            saver.writeBatch();
            SequenceRecordReader recordReader = new CSVSequenceRecordReader(0, ",");
            recordReader.initialize(new org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit(trainFile));
            SequenceRecordReader testReader = new CSVSequenceRecordReader(0, ",");
            testReader.initialize(new org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit(testFile));
            DataSetIterator iterator = new org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, 2, outputs, inputsTot, false);
            DataSetIterator testIterator = new org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator(testReader, 2, outputs, inputsTot, false);
            roc = new ArrayList < Map < String, Double >> ();
            String statMsg = "";
            Evaluation evaluation;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {

                    model.fit(iterator);
                    evaluation = model.evaluate(testIterator);
                } else {

                    model.fit(testIterator);
                    evaluation = model.evaluate(iterator);
                }
                Map < String, Double > map = new HashMap < String, Double > ();
                Map < Integer, Integer > falsePositives = evaluation.falsePositives();
                Map < Integer, Integer > trueNegatives = evaluation.trueNegatives();
                Map < Integer, Integer > truePositives = evaluation.truePositives();
                Map < Integer, Integer > falseNegatives = evaluation.falseNegatives();
                double fpr = falsePositives.get(1) / (falsePositives.get(1) + trueNegatives.get(1));
                double tpr = truePositives.get(1) / (truePositives.get(1) + falseNegatives.get(1));
                map.put("FPR", fpr);
                map.put("TPR", tpr);
                roc.add(map);
                statMsg = evaluation.stats();
                iterator.reset();
                testIterator.reset();
            }
            loadSaveNN(modelName, true);
            System.out.println("ROC " + roc);
            return statMsg;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error ocuured while building neural netowrk :" + e.getMessage());
            throw new NeuralException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public boolean generateModel(String modelName) {

        boolean status = false;
        try {    
            loadSaveNN(modelName, true);
            status = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error occurred:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return status;
    }

    private void loadSaveNN(String name, boolean save) {    

        File directory = new File(uploadDirectory);
        File[] allNN = directory.listFiles();
        boolean status = false;
        try {

            if (model == null && save) {

                buildModel();
            }
            if (allNN != null && allNN.length > 0) {
                for (File NN: allNN) {

                    String fnme = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(NN.getName());
                    if (name.equals(fnme)) {

                        status = true;
                        if (save) {

                            ModelSerializer.writeModel(model, NN, true);
                            System.out.println("Model Saved With Weights Successfully");

                        } else {

                            model = ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(NN);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!status && save) {

                //File tempFIle = File.createTempFile(name,".zip",directory);
                File tempFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name + ".zip");
                if (!tempFile.exists()) {

                    tempFile.createNewFile();
                }
                ModelSerializer.writeModel(model, tempFile, true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String testModel(String modelName, String[] rawData, Map < Integer, String > map, int inputs, int outputs, String ruleModelSavePath) throws Exception {

        String status = "";
        String fpath = uploadDirectory;
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(uploadDirectory + "original/insertdata.csv", true);
        fwriter.write("\n");
        fwriter.write(rawData[0]);
        fwriter.close();
        if (model == null) {
            loadSaveNN(modelName, false);
        }
        NormalizeDataset norm = new NormalizeDataset(uploadDirectory + "original/insertdata.csv");
        norm.updateStringValues(map);
        norm.whiteningData();
        norm.normalizeDataset();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(uploadDirectory + "originalnorminsertdata.csv")));
        String output = "";
        String prevOutput = "";
        while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            prevOutput = output;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        File readFile = new File(uploadDirectory + "normtest.csv");
        if (readFile.exists()) {

            readFile.delete();
        }
        readFile.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(readFile);
        writer.println(prevOutput);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        SequenceRecordReader recordReader = new CSVSequenceRecordReader(0, ",");
        recordReader.initialize(new org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit(new File(uploadDirectory + "normtest.csv")));
        DataSetIterator iterator = new org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, 2, outputs, inputs, false);
        INDArray outputArr = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            DataSet ds = iterator.next();
            INDArray provided = ds.getFeatureMatrix();
            outputArr = model.rnnTimeStep(provided);
        }
        //INDArray finalOutput = Nd4j.argMax(outputArr,1);
        double result = Double.parseDouble(Nd4j.argMax(outputArr, 1).toString());
        if (result == 0.0) {

            status = "Normal Transaction";
        } else {

            status = "Fraud Transaction, ";
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(uploadDirectory + "original/insertdata.csv")));
            String heading = "";
            heading = bufferedReader.readLine();
            bufferedReader.close();
            File ruleFile = new File(uploadDirectory + "normrules.csv");
            if (ruleFile.exists()) {

                ruleFile.delete();
            }
            ruleFile.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter writeNew = new PrintWriter(ruleFile);
            writeNew.println(heading);
            writeNew.println(rawData[0]);
            writeNew.flush();
            writeNew.close();
            RuleEngine engine = new RuleEngine(fpath + "original/insertdata.csv");
            engine.geneateModel(ruleModelSavePath, false);
            String finalStatus = status + "Attack Type:" + engine.predictionResult(uploadDirectory + "normrules.csv");
            status = finalStatus;
        }
        return status;
    }

    public void setUploadDirectory(String uploadDirectory) {    
        this.uploadDirectory = uploadDirectory;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FraudDetectorDeepBeilefNN neural_network = new FraudDetectorDeepBeilefNN();
        System.out.println("start=======================");
        try {
            neural_network.inputs = 4;
            neural_network.numHiddenNodes = 3;
            neural_network.HIDDEN_LAYER_COUNT = 2;
            neural_network.outputNum = 2;
            neural_network.buildModel();
            String output = neural_network.trainModel("nn", "D:/Data/a.csv", 2, 4);
            System.out.println(output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList < Map < String, Double >> getRoc() {
        return roc;
    }
}
```

Here is the 1st few lines of my dataset :

```
length,caplen,hlen,version,output
60,60,6,0,normal
243,243,8,0,normal
60,60,6,0,neptune
60,60,6,0,neptune
```

Comment: you need to provide a lot more precise information to get help, please edit your post with more specific information about where the error is occurring so we can have a lot more context, thanks!

Comment: formatting & rephrase

Comment: The community is active on Gitter. A lot of people there can help you: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j